# Probability of x independent events happening exactly n ore more times

Tags: probability

I was searching for an answer to my question, but I unfortunately couldn't 100% understand the formulas given. I'm a noob reading formulas. English is also not my first languague so please forgive me in case I write something wrong.

So now to my question:

It's related to a board game and there will be 4 out of 24 unique tiles showing up in the next round. Now I would like to know what's the probability of exactly any 2 out of 3 specific tiles to show up and also the probability of all 3 showing up.
Could you please also tell me the result of these 2 calculations? Then I will for sure understand the formulas aswell.

I think I know how to calculate the probability of 0 of these 3 tiles to show up.
I calculate that in this way: 21/24*20/23*19/22*18/21=0.56324110671936758893280632411067
~56.32% that none of these 3 tiles to show up

1-0.56324110671936758893280632411067=0.43675889328063241106719367588933
So the chance of 1 or more of these 3 tiles showing up is ~ 43.67%.
Is that right?

Thank you very much in advance! Your help is very much appreciated!
I am sorry for asking this question, because I believe it has alread been asked before.

Comment: Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) (i.e. LaTeX commands) for mathematical notations.

Answer (score 1):

Probability that exactly two of the specific three tiles will show up in the draw of 4 tiles from 24 = $$\frac{{3\choose2}{21\choose2}}{{24\choose4}} $$

${n\choose r} = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$

${3\choose 2} = \frac{3!}{2!1!} = \frac{3.2.1}{2.1} =3$

${24\choose 4} = \frac{24!}{4!20!} = \frac{24.23.22.21.20!}{4.3.2.1.20!} = \frac{24.23.22.21}{24} = 10626$

${21\choose 2} = \frac{21!}{2!19!} = \frac{21.20.19!}{2.19!} =210$

Answer for the first question $= \frac{3.210}{10626} = \frac{630}{10626} = .059288$

Probability that three of the specific three tiles will show up in the draw of 4 tiles from 24 = $$\frac{{3\choose3}{21\choose1}}{{24\choose4}}$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I still have the problem though of not knowing how to calculate it to get the results in percentage. How to calculate these? I know it's very simple, but I forgot how it works.

Comment: I have shown how to calculate for the first one, do the same for the other one

Comment: Thank you very much once again! I don't know how to write my calculation down in the correct way, but I think I calculated it in the right way via my calculator. The result I got was 0.00197628458498023715415019762846

Comment: You are correct for the second problem.  Good job done!!

Comment: Thank you! :) May I ask one more question? How to calculate a scenario where you want to know the probability of at least 2 of 4 specific tiles to show up in the draw of 4 tiles from 24?